# Classpath for the log4j2 config file in a subdirectory of my jar

Tags: java, classpath, log4j2

The path of my config file is `myJar.jar/resources/log4j2.xml`.

Like described in the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) (point 7), Log4j2 will automatically look for a log4j2.xml on the classpath.

Unfortunately this only works if my path is `myJar.jar/log4j2.xml`.

I tried to add the resources directory to my MANIFEST.MF in different ways, like
`Class-Path: resources`, without success.

How can I accomplish that? This should work both with my IDE while developing and with the final jar file.

Comment: What is wrong with `myJar.jar/log4j2.xml`?

Comment: I have multiple config files and I don't want them to be on the top level of my jar. Or is there a better place to store them?

Comment: But this is the place where the config file is looked up. After all ... it's a JAR. So, who cares?

Comment: Even if I'd save it on the top level, why does adding the resources directory to the classpath not work?

Comment: Additionally, Log4j respects the system property `log4j.configurationFile` with which you can configure a URL pointing to you configuration file. This is explained in the same documentation that you linked to.

Comment: Because te JAR is part of the class path. Not anything inside it. Specifying the directory `resurces` as part of the class path means having a directory _outside_ the JAR with that name.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the fact that that `log4j.configurationFile` takes a URL. That works! So it isn't possible to add `resources` to the classpath?